# My function is running more than once when I resize the page

Tags: jquery, function, resize

I need to work once in my page when resizing a page

```
<button></button>

function example(){
    $('button').click(function(){
    alert();
  });
}


$(window).bind('resize load', function(){

    if ( $(this).width() < 768 ){
    example();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcode/yh1m2vre/

Comment: Because you are binding the click event every time you are resizing and the width falls below 768. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Every time you re-size, you bind a new click event.  So after you've resized once, you have a click handler.  After you resize again, you have 2 click handlers (which do the same thing).  Then 4, then 8, then 16, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I do not know how I can prevent this.

Comment: @vulkan - What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @nikhil If it falls below 768, run it once

Comment: If it is less than 768, then you want alert on click of button? And if it is more than 768 then you do not want alert on the click of button? Also, do you want to fire the alert automatically when you resize the window and width falls below 768 i.e. without even clicking the button?

Comment: Check the width when the user clicks the button and only run example if <768.  Why would you want a button they user can't click (when screen is larger)?  (**Edit:** as Rory has provided details in an answer)

Comment: @nikhil [If it is less than 768, then you want one alert on click of button] <- ı want . And thank you for your help.

Comment: @vulkan - I am just curious now. Then the answer you have selected does not hold true. Because, when you bring down the width to less than 768 and then increase the width to more than 768 and then click the button. Alert will still fire

Comment: sorry. Maybe I could not tell. But the answer I chose works just the way I want it. If you fall below every 768, you only have to work 1 time. (sorry my english)

Comment: @vulkan - This time I understood your problem and then the accepted solution is the one you were looking for. Thank you for clarifying the requirement and kudos to Joscplan for sensing it correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unbind the click event every time you call your function, you can do so like this:

```
function example(){
    $('button').off().on("click", function(){
        alert();
    });
}
```

That way it prevents event triggering duplication.

The other solution is to bind the click event outside your function and then just trigger the click action. You can do it this way:

```
$('button').on("click", function(){
    alert();
});

function example(){
    $('button').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have explained in the comments, the issue is because you're binding multiple new `click()` event handlers every time the `resize` event occurs.

To fix this problem it would be better to invert the logic so that you only check the width of the screen within a single click handler, and then act accordingly.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  if ($(window).width() >= 768)
    return;

  console.log('window size < 768');
});
```

Having the logic organised in this manner means that you only ever have a single event handler for the lifespan of the page, instead of potentially adding/removing new ones hundreds, if not thousands, of times.

Answer (score 0):

Add event listeners:

```
    function callbackFunc() {
        callAnOtherFunction();
    }

    // listen for events
    window.addEventListener("resize", callbackFunc);
```